# Who developed Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) and applied it to machine learning?

Tags: mathematicians, computer-science, statistics, probability, machine-learning

I searched about GMM ([Gaussian mixture model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Gaussian_mixture_model)), but only found that normal distribution was invented by Carl Friedrich Gauss. I'd like to know who contributed to the development of GMM itself, and to using it for machine learning.

Comment: The earliest mixture models were Gaussian mixtures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#History so Pearson at least, but arguably Quetelet ...  (I was looking at Pearson 1894 mentioned there only a few days ago -- it certainly seems to qualify as using a Gaussian mixture model) ...

Answer (score 3):

The idea of using Gaussian mixtures was popularized by Duda and Hart in their seminal 1973 text, *Pattern Classification and Scene Analysis*.